# Rのデフォルトパッケージstatsを消してしまい、「パッケージ ‘stats’ は名前空間を持っていません」と表示される

Tags: r

助けてください。
Rのデフォルトパッケージであるstatsを消してしまいました。

以下、経緯

- filter_やmutate_はfunctionで使えませんと出たため、ネットで検索
  →とあるブログに「removeでstatsを消せばいい」とあり、実行
- tidyverseやその他もろもろ、これまで重宝してきたパッケージが全て使えなくなる

現状では以下のように表示されます。

```
library(tidyverse)
 エラー: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
  パッケージ ‘stats’ は名前空間を持っていません
```

Rstudioを再起動させる時にも以下のように表示され、どうしようも無くなっています。

```
 起動準備中です -  警告メッセージ: 
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
 エラー: package ‘stats’ does not have a namespace
 警告:  namespace ‘stats’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘full.model’

 エラー: package ‘stats’ does not have a namespace
 エラー: package ‘stats’ does not have a namespace
 エラー: package ‘stats’ does not have a namespace
 エラー: package ‘stats’ does not have a namespace
```

R自体をアンインストールしようかとも考えたのですが、これまでのファイルが消える可能性もあると聞き怖くてできていません。
また、statsを再インストールしても、その後tidyverse等をインストールできませんでした。

大学で使うのに、課題が終わっていないのに、と絶望しています。誰か助けてください。

Comment: 「statsを再インストールしても、その後tidyverse等をインストールできませんでした」はもう少し具体的にどういうことでしょうか？インストールを試みたけどエラーでできなかった？ということですか？

Answer (score 0):

`library(tidyverse)`の代わりに`library(dplyr)`を使用してみたらどうでしょうか？
tidyverseはdplyrが中に入っているため、dplyrでも代用可能な気がします。
あとはfilterとかだと他のパッケージにも同じ名前の関数が入っているため、
dplyr::mutateやdplyr::filterと書くとかしたら改善できませんか？